# xcopy command to move app.manifest from obj to bin folder failed on build server

Tags: c#, wpf, tfs, msbuild

I have added `app.manifest` file to my WPF client project to make it to Run as Admin. I was getting `app.manifest` file not found in bin folder error. I resolved this issue by adding XCopy command in post build event of my project.
XCOPY command copies manifest files from obj folder to bin folder.
My project builds successfully locally.

```
%windir%\system32\xcopy "$(SolutionDir)AppName\obj\$(Configuration)\AppName.exe.manifest" "$(SolutionDir)AppName\bin\$(Configuration)" /i /D /y /s /r /c

%windir%\system32\xcopy "$(SolutionDir)AppName\obj\$(Configuration)\AppName.application" "$(SolutionDir)AppName\bin\$(Configuration)" /i /D /y /s /r /c
```

But when I check-in TFS, I am getting build error in Build server. Manifest files are not created in the obj folder on the build server.

I am not getting how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Copy the generated manifest to your project folder, add it as part of the solution, and   set file as 'content'.  This will automatically do what you are trying to do manually.

Comment: The manifest applies attributes to the exe at compile time. You don't copy it anywhere else. If you did, it would have no effect. And it needs to be called app.manifest. Exactly that. Not AppName.exe.manifest or anything else.  It should be build action None Copy to output directory: Do not copy. These are what you get when you add > new item > application manifest

Answer (score 1):

Add the manifest file to your project in Visual Studio and set its `Build Action` property to `Content` and its `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer`. Then it will be copied to the output folder when you build without you having to use any manual `xcopy` commands.

Comment: If I remove xcopy commands and clean build then I am getting build failed in local also saying app.manifest file not found in output directory.